# Find and Replace in Excel with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a column with computer names however the names are formatted like this domain\computer name. Usually in Excel I can use find/replace and search for *\ and replace with blank leaving just the computer name. I have a powershell script that finds *\ however it replaces the whole cell with nothing. It's like its searching for any cell that contains *\ and replacing that instead of just leaving the computer name.

```
$file = "C:\reports\report.xls"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Workbok = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)
$Worksheets = $Workbook.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Worksheet = $Workbok.Worksheets.Item(1)
$SearchString = "*\"
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)
if($search -ne $null){
$FirstAddress = $Search.Address
do{
$Search.value() = ""
$search = $Range.FindNext($search)
}while ($search -ne $null -and $search.Address -ne $FirstAddress)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Do-While loop you are taking the value of the search and setting it to an empty string. `$Search.value() = ""`. If you take that and change it something like this `$search.Value() = $Search.value() -replace "^.*\\",''` it should work. I used -replace with some regex to replace everything from the backslash until the beginning of the line.

Cleaned up your code a bit because it seems you had some misspelled variables

```
$file = "C:\reports\report.xls"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$SearchString = "*\"
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("A1").EntireColumn
$Search = $Range.find($SearchString)
if ($search -ne $null) {
    $FirstAddress = $Search.Address
    do {
        $search.Value() = $Search.value() -Replace "^.*\\", ''  
        $search = $Range.FindNext($search)
    } while ($search -ne $null -and $search.Address -ne $FirstAddress)
}
```

Comment: That is outstanding, thank you that worked perfectly. I also noticed the typo's thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Probably should mark it as accepted answer..